# Bootstrap selectpicker option always selected

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-selectpicker

I need option x to be always selected inside the selected.(Disable unselect for this option).

here is my current template code

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-size="5" data-max-options="10" class="selectpicker multi-select" name="brand">
    <option value="x" >X</option>
    <option value="y" >Y</option>    
</select>
```

Desired output: Option X should be mandatory/always selected/cannot be unselected.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED.**

<strike>Add both selected and disabled html attributes:</strike>

Adding selected and disabled attributes doesn't work on all browser. You can achieve this only by javascript, by adding an event listener on change of the `<select>` element.

The code in javascript is:

```
document.querySelector("[name='brand']").addEventListener('change', function() { 
    document.querySelector("[name='brand'] option[value='x']").selected = true;
});
```

Here is a working example on codepen:
[Multiple select mandatory option](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mvGGgg)

Comment: can i do it using jQuery? or JS?

Comment: i used the template <disabled> and passing $().val("x") always to make it work. The JS snippet did not work as expected

Comment: that's strange, cause what you did is a jQuery version of the code I posted in vanilla Javascript. The CodePen example works too, but glad you solved it either-way.